# Finding files for which a command fails

Tags: files, scripting, find, exit-status

I would like to recursively find all the files for which a script which accepts a file as an argument returns a non-zero value. Any idea how to do this using 'find' or a similar tool?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`find`’s `-exec` action can be used for this:

```
find . \! -exec yourscript {} \; -print
```

will print the names of all files for which `yourscript` fails.

`-exec` can be used in this way to turn appropriate external commands into `find` tests.

You can limit the files which are tested by adding `find` tests before `-exec`; for example, to limit the candidates to regular files, add `-type f`:

```
find . -type f \! -exec yourscript {} \; -print
```

Comment: Equivalently, using `-o` (or): `find . -exec yourscript {} \; -o -print`.